# Hacker Rank Sparse Arrays

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

There is a collection of input strings and a collection of query strings. For each query string, determine how many times it occurs in the list of input strings. Return an array of the results.
Example:-
strings = ['ab',' ab','abc']
queries = ['ab', ' abc','bc']
There are 2 instances of 'ab', 1 of 'abc',0 of 'bc'. For each query, add an element to the return array.
results = [2,1,0]

**Function Description**

Complete the function matchingStrings in the editor below. The function must return an array of integers representing the frequency of occurrence of each query string in strings.

matchingStrings has the following parameters:

string strings[n] - an array of strings to search
string queries[q] - an array of query strings
Returns

int[q]: an array of results for each query

Constraints:

1 <=len(strings) <= 1000,

1 <=len(queries) <= 1000
1 <= string[i] <= 20,

1<=query[i]<= 20

This is my code. It runs successfully on sample test cases but fails for 10/13 test cases.

```
#Code in python
def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
#first few lines satisfies the constraints
    if len(strings) >= 1 and len(strings)<= 1000:
        if len(queries)>= 1 and len(strings)<= 1000:
            count_arr = {} # creating a dict to save each query count
            for query in queries:
                if len(query)>= 1 and len(query)<= 20:
                    count_arr[query] = 0
                    for string in strings:
                        if len(string)>= 1 and len(string)<= 20:
                            if query  == string.strip():
                                count_arr[query] = count_arr[query] + 1
    return list(count_arr.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter


def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    count = Counter(strings)
    return [count[query] for query in queries]
```

Example:

```
>>> matchingStrings(['ab', 'ab', 'abc'], ['ab', 'abc', 'bc'])
[2, 1, 0]
```

If you can't use `collections.Counter` you can implement your version:

```
def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    count = {}
    for s in strings:
        count[s] = count.get(s, 0) + 1
    return [count.get(query, 0) for query in queries]
```

Comment: We can only use the following modules:- math, os, random, re, sys

Comment: @NikhilNarayane Check the new version

Comment: Thanks Riccardo, but can you also tell what is wrong with my code. Why am I getting  10 failed cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    # Write your code here
    output = []
    for i in range(len(queries)):
        output.append(strings.count(queries[i]))

    return output
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details about your code. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).